# Monitoring Landscape on prem server services

Tags: services, landscape, monitoring

If you are running an on prem instance of Landscape, do you monitor the essential services?  If so, what are they?
-apache2
-landscape_service
-etc

Comment: This type of question is better suited to Ubuntu Forums, as it's asking for multiple responses. It is too broad and subjective, and so off topic for Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on version of Ubuntu you have and Landscape server but here is a good start. Looking into lsctl, which you can use to restart landscape server when required with its services (`lsctl restart`)

> cat /usr/bin/lsctl

Below is list of services that can be monitored.
    ...

```
# basename of init script
SVC_APPSERVER="landscape-appserver"
SVC_ASYNC_FRONTEND="landscape-async-frontend"
SVC_JOBHANDLER="landscape-job-handler"
SVC_MSGSERVER="landscape-msgserver"
SVC_PINGSERVER="landscape-pingserver"
SVC_APISERVER="landscape-api"
SVC_JUJU_SYNC="landscape-juju-sync"
SVC_PACKAGEUPLOADSERVER="landscape-package-upload"
SVC_PACKAGESEARCH="landscape-package-search"
SVC_PPPA_PROXY="landscape-pppa-proxy"
SVC_CRON="landscape-cron"
...
```

Hope this will help.
Thanks